# AngularJS: How to properly communicate ebwteen Controller and Service' method

Tags: angularjs

I'm just a beginner at AngularJS. I'm trying to construct a method call on my Angular data service, to which I pass an object that needs to be posted to the server. The Name of the data service is requestsRepository and the name of the controller is EnterNewRequestCtrl. My service has a method "postServiceRequest", to which I'm trying to pass my data object to be posted. When I call this methon from the controller, I get the following error:  TypeError: Cannot call method 'postServiceRequest' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.submitRequest (http://myhost.mydomain.com:9221/controllers/EnterNewRequestCtrl.js:9:28)

Here is a complete listing of both the service and the controller.

The service:

```
frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository', function ($http) {

   var postServiceRequest =  function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/Customers',
            method: "POST",
            data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
            console.log("postServiceRequest SUCCESS");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.status = status;
            console.log("postServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status);
        });
    }
});
```

And now the controller:

```
angular.module('frontEndApp').controller('EnterNewRequestCtrl',function ($scope, requestsRepository) {
    $scope.RequestorName;
    $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit;
    $scope.submitRequest = function () {
        var ServiceRequest = {
            requestorName: $scope.RequestorName,
            requestorBusinessUnit: $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit
        };
        requestsRepository.postServiceRequest(ServiceRequest);
    }
  });
```

What is the proper way of implementing this controller - server method call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an object with a `postServiceRequest()` method on it...

```
frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository', function ($http) {

   var postServiceRequest =  function (ServiceRequest) {
        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/Customers',
            method: "POST",
            data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
            console.log("postServiceRequest SUCCESS");
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.status = status;
            console.log("postServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status);
        });
    };
    return { postServiceRequest : postServiceRequest };
});
```

-- Edit --

Once you get that working, you also should change postServiceRequest() to return the promise from the $http() call, then use that promise in your controller to populate the variables on the $scope...

```
var frontEndApp = angular.module('frontEndApp', []);

frontEndApp.factory('requestsRepository', function ($http) {

   var postServiceRequest =  function (ServiceRequest) {
        return $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/Customers',
            method: "POST",
            data: ServiceRequest,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
    return { postServiceRequest : postServiceRequest };
});

frontEndApp.controller('EnterNewRequestCtrl',function ($scope, requestsRepository) {
    $scope.RequestorName;
    $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit;
    $scope.submitRequest = function () {
        var ServiceRequest = {
            requestorName: $scope.RequestorName,
            requestorBusinessUnit: $scope.RequestorBusinessUnit
        };
        requestsRepository.postServiceRequest(ServiceRequest)
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //$scope.persons = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here 
                console.log("postServiceRequest SUCCESS");
            }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //$scope.status = status;
                console.log("postServiceRequest FAILURE: " + status);
            });
    };
});
```

Comment: No worries... might be some subtle errors in the code still but that should be the idea.